# Unable to access router throug 192.168.1.1

Tags: networking, router

I have a Vigor2100G that was on a box for about three years. 
Now i want to use it and the router works well, i can use it as a switch for all my computers, but the problem comes when i try to access the router configuration. I do a ping on the port 192.168.1.1 and all works fine. The PC detects the router and the router gives a response to the computer.

When i try to connect to the router through firefox on Kali Linux (tried also on Windows 10 and Windows 7) the page doesn't loads and gives back an error that says that time has exceed.

Thanks for the answer, hope it cames soon.

Answer (score 1):

Not all routers use 192.168.1.1 as their gateway address.  The ability to ping that IP doesn't necessarily indicate that it is the router that you are pinging, only that something is using that IP and responding.  Additionally, most routers will not allow you to connect to their interface via wireless (by default, at least), so make sure you are connected with a network cable.

To make sure you are trying to hit the correct IP for your router, try this:

- Open a Command Prompt
- type in `ipconfig`
- Find the Ethernet adapter in question
- Find the default gateway for that adapter
- The default gateway may give you an IPv6 address (letters and numbers) as well as an IPv4 address (just numbers).  You want the one that is just numbers.
- Use that IP in your browser to try and connect.

[Screenshot of ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXhCA.png)

Answer (score 0):

The router's IP is probably correct according to http://www.draytek-mx.com/support/support_note/router/faq/basic/05.php .

Maybe a hardware reset will help by pressing the factory reset button as mentioned in the link.